# Visual Studio Code move implementation from .h to .cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Is there a fast way to move function implementations from a header file to its corresponding source file in VS Code? Or vice versa? Something similar to what visual assist has https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W702

One can cut and paste, but it's not always that simple. Ex. class member functions need to add `class_name::`, which can be tedious when there are many member functions.

Answer (score 4):

I [asked about this in the Discussion board for the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11188#discussioncomment-6443553). One of the maintainers, Sean Mcmanus replied:

> VS 2022 has this feature (Move Definition):
>
> [image]
>
> We're currently working on the Extract Function refactoring instead [#1162](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1162), but Move Definition could potential be added to VS Code in the future (the work on Extract Function could make the Move Definition work faster to do).

I'll be following that work and will update this answer post with progress.